# simplexml add child non attribute information

Tags: php, xml

i'm trying to figure out how to add this right here;

```
<tech name="level 0" prereq="0" id="7" null="null">
<meta fuelx="1" energyx="1" cost="100" income="11">Description goes here</meta>
</tech>
```

to an already existing xml file.

I've gotten the first  and the  but I cannot figure out how to add the information between the &.

Comment: I don't even see an *&* in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add child nodes w/ SimpleXML. You can convert to DOM and then do it though.

```
$curNode  = dom_import_simplexml($simpleXml);
$newChild = dom_import_simplexml($sXml);
$tmpNode  = $curNode->ownerDocument->importNode($newChild, true);
$curNode->appendChild($tmpNode);
```

**EDIT**

Wow, it seems like they added an [`addChild`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) method in 5.1.3, where have I been??